# Как добавить класс при достижении блока?

Tags: javascript

Как добавить класс при достижении блока .about__container . Вроде все правильно, но класс не добавляется. Спасибо

```js
const pageAbout = document.querySelector('.about__container');
const position = pageAbout.offsetTop;
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const height = pageAbout.offsetHeight;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
    var scroll = body.scrollTop;
    if (scroll > position && scroll < (position + height)) {
        pageAbout.classList.add("_active")
    } else {
        pageAbout.classList.remove("_active")
    }
});
```

```css
.header{
  height: 1000px;
}

.about__container{
  background: red;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.about__container._active{
  background: green;
}

.footer{
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="about__container"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Если заменить **... body.scrollTop;** на **... window.pageYOffset;** класс добавляется при достижении **about__container** вверх экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Так как элемент body не может быть прокручен, то `scrollTop = 0`, вам нужно использовать `window.pageYOffset`:

```
var scroll = window.pageYOffset;
```

Подробнее про [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) и [pageYOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset)